# Unable to find the proper way to handle recovery in Spring Kafka

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I'm working on a fairly simple Spring Boot app which will process messages from a single topic and then invoke an external web service for each message. I want this service to be somewhat smart about errors, so that if for example the external web site is not available for a short period, records should be retried with expoential backoff until some point where we give up and just log the error and commit the record.

I'm using Spring Boot and Spring Kafka 2.3.3.

I'll show you some of the Spring configuration I have for this setup. Some things left out for brevity. Ask if there is some value or other configuration that might be helpful.

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class SpringConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrap_servers);
        // .. Misc other properties related to serialisation etc ..
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public SeekToCurrentErrorHandler eh() {
        long initialMillis = 500;
        long factor = 2;
        long maxElapsedTimeSecs = 60;
        ExponentialBackOff backoff = new ExponentialBackOff(initialMillis, factor);
        backoff.setMaxElapsedTime(maxElapsedTimeSecs*1000);

        BiConsumer<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>, Exception> recoverer = (rec, exc) ->  {
           // TODO In the final app do something more useful here
           logger.error("* Maximum retry policy has been reached {} - acknowledging and proceeding *", rec);
        };

        SeekToCurrentErrorHandler eh = new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(recoverer, backoff);
        eh.setCommitRecovered(true);
        return eh;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(RetryTemplate retryTemplate) {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setMissingTopicsFatal(missingTopicsFatal); // True in prod, false otherwise

 factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommitTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60));
        factory.setStatefulRetry(true);
        factory.setErrorHandler(eh());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

My Listener is very simple:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.input_topic}")
public void handle(ConsumerRecord<String, SendToEBoksMessage> record, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Listener invoked");
    // TODO Right so simulate some sort of problem. External web service not available, for example.
    throw new Exception("Exception of some kind");
}
```

But it seems that the increasing delays introduced by the `ExponentialBackoff` parameter to the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` causes a rebalance to occur in Kafka. After retrying a few times the log shows this rebalance taking place:

```
...
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void MyListenerClass.handle(org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord<java.lang.String, MyMessageClass>,org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment) throws java.lang.Exception' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.Exception: Exception of some kind; nested exception is java.lang.Exception: Exception of some kind
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.decorateException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1686)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Exception of some kind
    at MyListenerClass.handle(SendToEboksMessageKafkaListener.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

2019-12-16 12:49:04.364  INFO michael-laptop --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator          : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=mygroupid] Revoking previously assigned partitions [MyTopic-0]
2019-12-16 12:49:04.365  INFO michael-laptop --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : MyTopic: partitions revoked: [MyTopic-0]
2019-12-16 12:49:04.365  INFO michael-laptop --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator          : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=mygroupid] (Re-)joining group
2019-12-16 12:49:04.373  INFO michael-laptop --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.AbstractCoordinator          : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=mygroupid] Successfully joined group with generation 18
2019-12-16 12:49:04.373  INFO michael-laptop --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.i.ConsumerCoordinator          : [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=mygroupid] Setting newly assigned partitions: 
2019-12-16 12:49:04.373  INFO michael-laptop --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : ...
```

I don't understand why this is happening. From what I read, using the error handler for recovery this way would cause the retry to be handled by the container and avoid potential problems with not invoking `consumer.poll()` often enough to satisy the `max.poll.ms` property.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

*** Update:

I'm seeing the following in the Kafka broker logs:

```
[2019-12-17 14:13:22,714] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Preparing to rebalance group MyGroup1 in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 0 (__consumer_offsets-37) (reason: Adding new member consumer-1-2d76a488-3677-4294-9aed-c153f0dca66c with group instanceid None) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2019-12-17 14:13:22,722] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Stabilized group MyGroup1 generation 1 (__consumer_offsets-37) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2019-12-17 14:13:22,735] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Assignment received from leader for group MyGroup1 for generation 1 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2019-12-17 14:14:18,096] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Preparing to rebalance group MyGroup1 in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 1 (__consumer_offsets-37) (reason: Adding new member consumer-1-addbdcfd-21ed-44fa-9d17-b10c7c67f07f with group instanceid None) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2019-12-17 14:14:20,161] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Stabilized group MyGroup1 generation 2 (__consumer_offsets-37) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
[2019-12-17 14:14:20,163] INFO [GroupCoordinator 1001]: Assignment received from leader for group MyGroup1 for generation 2 (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)
```

Comment: Since you are using stateful recovery with a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`, the retries are performed by re-seeking and re-polling the consumer. Since your `maxElapsedTime` is 60 seconds, assuming you have the default `max.poll.interval.ms` of 5 minutes, then it would appear that something else is causing the rebalance; perhaps another instance joining the group? Perhaps look at the server log to see if there are any clues there.

Comment: @GaryRussell Thanks for your reply. I ran my consumer with TRACE level debugging which unfortunately did not reveal anything other than the "partitions revoked" message. I ran my Kafka broker with DEBUG logging and all I see there is "Preparing to restabilize group" again with no discernable reason. The thing is my consumer seems to complete just fine and commit my recovered record at the end as expected, despite multiple rebalances during the backoff and retry cycle. I'm not sure if I should even be worried, but the rebalance thing feels like a red flag to me.

Comment: As long as `poll()` is called within `max.poll.interval.ms` you should not see a rebalance. Something is definitely wrong if that's not what's happening. Only if your `listener run time before failing + the 60 seconds backoff` exceeds the poll interval should you see a rebalance. Unfortunately such a situation is outside the Spring realm and not something I can help with.

Comment: And since I am using stateful retry and a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` the exponentially increasing backoff period should not count against the time a consumer has before it has to invoke `poll()` again - right? I should perhaps mention that the first rebalance occurs very shortly after the message is posted to the topic and consumed by my consumer. We're not talking minutes or even seconds here, it happens right after the first exception from the `@KafkaListener` has been handled in the error handler.

Comment: @GaryRussell Just updated the description with some interesting log statements from my Kafka broker. I updated the broker to version 2.4.0 and it now provides a reason for the rebalance (see the updated description at the bottom). It appears that Kafka believes a consumer is being added and so forces the rebalance. Why would this be happening?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry; you haven't set `concurrency` on the container so Spring will only start one consumer. Maybe some kind of network problem interfering with heartbeats? I think the kafka consumer client logs heartbeat info (maybe trace or debug).

Comment: I have everything running locally on my machine so network should not be an issue. My consumer (spring boot app) periodically lists that "Attempt to heartbeat failed since group is rebalancing". So yes heartbeat is a problem but only because the group is already rebalancing. Can you perhaps point me to what you believe is a working and "current" example of stateful retry with an error handler? Perhaps I can try to run that code with my broker - see if that works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the solution was quite different from what I expected.

My Spring Boot application works just fine, including the retry policy and recovery handler I use to construct a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler`.

The problem was due to how my test messages were being committed to the topic. I would run the app in a console using something like

```
$ mvn spring-boot:run
```

And once that was up and running with  a consumer, I would then use my eclipse IDE to run a unit test to place a message on that topic.

However, since the unit test reuses the same Spring configuration as the main app, the test would not only get a producer ready and post the message, it would also initialize a consumer with the exact same properties as the one in use by the main app. And as this second consumer joined the group, the rebalance would occur. Another rebalance would occur as  the test finished.

This is all perfectly logical once you think it through, and completely explains the rebalancing I was seeing in the log output from the console app.

Big thanks to Gary Russell for helping out - really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an app that I wrote some time ago; I updated it to Boot 2.2.2 and it works fine:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Kgh1234Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Kgh1234Application.class, args);
    }


    @KafkaListener(id = "kgh1234", topics = "kgh1234")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
        if (in.endsWith("5")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("fail");
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(
            ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer,
            ConsumerFactory<Object, Object> kafkaConsumerFactory) {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<Object, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        configurer.configure(factory, kafkaConsumerFactory);
        factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(new FixedBackOff(0L, 2L)));
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public NewTopic topic() {
        return new NewTopic("kgh1234", 32, (short) 1);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(i -> template.send("kgh1234", "foo" + i));
        };
    }

}
```

and

```
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
```

It just uses the default recoverer which simply logs when retries are exhausted.

> foo5
>
> 2019-12-17 10:50:32.018 ERROR 32052 --- [  kgh1234-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler        : Backoff FixedBackOff{interval=0, currentAttempts=3, maxAttempts=2} exhausted for ConsumerRecord(topic = kgh1234, partition = 1, leaderEpoch = 0, offset = 0, CreateTime = 1576597830940, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 4, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = foo5)

Comment: Actually, `setStatefulRetry` is only needed when there is a retry template; it is ignored otherwise; which is no longer needed since we have a `BackOff` in the error handler. I have updated my example to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this example. I noticed you use a `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer` which I do not. I'm trying to understand what the purpose of that class is and if I need it or not? What does it configure?

Comment: Oooooohhhhhh. I think I understand what is going on now. My app is structured in two parts: The app itself (SpringBootApplication) and a unit test which produces a message to put on the topic. I run the app in a bash console and the test from within my eclipse environment. But when the test runs it uses the same Spring configuration as the app, which includes the consumer bean definition. When the consumer is initialized by the test, I'm thinking it somehow interferes with the consumer already running in the console app, thus causing the rebalance.

Comment: The configurer applies any `spring.kafka.listener.*` properties from `application.properties` or `application.yml`. Yes; starting another consumer with the same group will cause a rebalance. You can use `autoStartup="$(testing:true)"` to the `@KafkaListener` then start your CLI app with `-Dtesting=false`.